# Add marquee as part of ab headline

Tags: html, css, customization, elementor, marquee

So with the possibilities of HTML marquee, I came super close to what I want to create.

```css
.marquee {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.marquee span {
    font-size: 40px;
    position: relative;
    left: 100%;
    animation: marquee 2s linear infinite;
}

.marquee:hover span {
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

.marquee span:nth-child(1) {
    animation-delay: 0s;
}
.marquee span:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: 0.8s;
}
.marquee span:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: 1.6s;
}
.marquee span:nth-child(4) {
    animation-delay: 2.4s;
}
.marquee span:nth-child(5) {
    animation-delay: 3.2s;
}


@keyframes marquee {
    0% {left: 100%;}
    100% {left: -100%;}
}


p{
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<p class="marquee">
    <span>this is a</span>
    <span>simple marquee</span>
    <span>using css</span>
    <span>using css</span>
    <span>simple marquee</span>
 </p>
```

The only 2 problems:

1. I don't know how to change the height so that the text will stay in the middle
2. The words overlap and I can't create a clean loop of the words

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

I assume I made it. If anything inside this code is a no-go, please let me know.

If not, this will be a possible CSS only solution for anybody who wants to achieve something similar:

HTML:

```
  <div class="marqueemagic">
  <div class="scrollingquee">
    
  </div><div class="scrollingquee" aria-hidden="true">
    <i> CONVERSION | OPTIMIZATION |</i>
  </div><div class="scrollingquee" aria-hidden="true">
     <i>CONVERSION | OPTIMIZATION |</i>
  </div><div class="scrollingquee" aria-hidden="true">
    <i> CONVERSION | OPTIMIZATION |</i>
  </div>
  <!-- … -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.marqueemagic {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  font-size: 35px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.scrollingquee {
  animation: marquee 5s linear infinite;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  to { 
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

Result:

https://youtu.be/Tuy4FUZmVd8

Of course, you can change speed, width, background color, opacity, font related values etc. as you wish without breaking anything.

With kind regards
Chris